# Web server not displaying pages, and apache error 403 for new files

Tags: web-server, php, apache-httpd

After setting up a web server on my pi following the instructions here - http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server, everything goes fine except for when I view the web server. The test file loaded fine, but when I uploaded my own files via FTP they were not displayed in my browser, although it loaded the link. A blank page would just come up. After trying to create a new HTML file, Apache error 403 appeared on my screen.

(I installed VSFTP)

Any help with written ssh commands would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the permissions of the files you uploaded.  Try using this command to make your files accessible:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R /var/www
```

Comment: To automate this you can use set group permissions on `/val/www`. Make sure that /var/www has group ownership by the web-server. Then `chgrp -R web-owner /var/www && chmod -R g+s /var/www` where `web-owner` is what ever it was before.